# Why does is pid not correct and changing continuously compared against Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, terminal, process

quick question:

Assume, I'd like to kill iTunes. In bash/terminal I run:
`ps aux | grep itunes`
When I execute this command several times, the `pid` changes (actually it increments).

When having a look at the *ActivityMonitor.app* the `pid` (obviously) does not change and differs from what the terminal command gives me.

Anyone has an idea what the issue might be?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly capturing the PID of grep rather than the iTunes process. Try the following:

```
ps aux | grep iTunes | egrep -v "grep|Helper" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Unless you use the '-i' option with grep you are searching with case sensitivity. The process command name is "iTunes".

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
  sudo kill -9 pid_of_the_app
```

According to the manual, *man kill*,

```
   Some of the more commonly used signals:
 1       HUP (hang up)
 2       INT (interrupt)
 3       QUIT (quit)
 6       ABRT (abort)
 9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)
 14      ALRM (alarm clock)
 15      TERM (software termination signal)
```